# Search for a "string" or "String with Spaces" recursively that may be a file- or directory-name or a text inside a file

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, find

I would like to search for the string `rstudio` (and its different possible combinations mentioned below) recursively starting from `/`.

In some locations, `rstudio` is a string inside another file (but this file-name is not known); and in other locations, `rstudio` itself is a (part of a) file-name (e.g., `rstudio 2023-10-20` or `2022-10-20-rstudio-file`), and this (part of a) file-name is not known. Also, to make matters more complicated, sometimes it is `RStudio` and sometimes it is `R Studio` – different cases and/or with spaces.

To summarize, the possible combinations are

- `rstudio` is a string inside a file
- `rstudio` is a file-name
- `rstudio` is a directory-name

In each of the above three lines, do consider that the string can be `rstudio` or `R Studio` or `Rstudio` or `r Studio` or `2022-10-20 RStudio file`. (I hope you get the various possible situations.)

For the output,

- if `rstudio` (or any of its above combinations) is the name of a file, then I need the name of the directory for that file,

and

- if `rstudio` (or any of its above combinations) is a string inside another file, then I need the corresponding file-name and its location.

Can someone please help me? I looked up on a few answers using `find` and `grep` but I am not able to get it.

Comment: But it will always be either `rstudio` or `R Studio`, is that correct? Never `studioR` or `r studio` or `r Studio` or anything else?

Comment: Yes  it is always r{1 space}studio but it can be capitals ;)

Comment: Can it, @Rinzwind? The OP only mentions those two exact cases: `rstudio` and `R Studio`. Why do you say the case can change? And why do you say it is always `r{1 space}`? That one we already know is false since the OP mentioned `rstudio`.

Comment: @terdon - Hello! Yes, it can be `r Studio` or `R studio` or any text before/after `R studio` or `r Studio` or any such combinations of `rstudio`; but it will **not** be `Studio R`.

Comment: @Rinzwind -Hello! Yes, that is true, but it can also be any combination of `some_text_before` and/or `some_text_after` `rstudio` (and all possible combinations of `rstudio`).

Comment: ... what about strings like "Microsoft Develope**r Studio**"?

Comment: @steeldriver - Hello! Those type of matches are not to be considered. And thank you for the **bold**, it took some time but finally helped me understand what you're saying. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't done any profiling, but it *may* be faster to do a single recursive descent rather than a separate `find` and recursive `grep`. Some other potential optimizations:

1. avoid searching `/dev` and ephemeral directories `/proc`, `/sys` etc.
2. don't search *inside* files that have already been selected based on their name
3. avoid searching inside binary files using grep's `-I` or `--binary-files=without-match`
4. use grep's fixed string mode, since neither `rstudio` nor `R studio` has any regular expression metacharacters - note that GNU grep still honors the case-insensitive `-i` and word-boundary flag `-w` in this mode, so we avoid matches like `Developer Studio`.

So

```
find / \( -path /dev -o -path /proc -o -path /run -o -path /sys \) -prune \
    -o \( -iname '*rstudio*' -o -iname '*r studio*' \) -printf '%h/\n' \
    -o -type f -exec grep -IFiwl -e 'rstudio' -e 'r studio' -- {} +
```

I used `-printf '%h/\n'` rather than plain `-printf '%h\n'` because the trailing `/` makes it easier to distinguish whether the match was by name or by content.

Note that even with the pruning, you should expect many "Permission denied" errors unless the above is run as root.

Comment: that sure is a monster of a "find". big fan of monsters :+)

Comment: @Rinzwind lol well I tried to format it into recognizable chunks (prune, then match names, then grep)

Comment: I would be hesitant to include optimization 3 as general guidance unless specifically told that binary files aren't relevant.  Someone will end up missing a file where the string was a reference to a shared lib or in the header of a custom binary file or in the EXIF data of an image or who knows what else.

Answer (score 6):

This will be slow, but if you need to look at all the files on your system, that will always be slow. I would do this in two passes. One, with `find` to look for file names and the other, with `grep` to look at file contents.

1. Find files whose name contains the string `rstudio` or `R Studio`, case insensitively, and print the name of the directory containing them.

   ```
   find / \( -iname "*rstudio*" -or -iname "*R Studio*") -printf '%h\n'
   ```

   This will look search all files (and directories, and anything else) in the `/` directory whose name contains one of the two desired strings and then print the directory name (`%h`, see `man find`). You can pass this through `sort -u` to remove duplicates. To avoid permission denied warnings, either add `2> /dev/null` to the end, or run as root:

   ```
   sudo find \( -iname "*rstudio*" -or -iname "*R Studio*" \) -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
   ```

   or, if you don't care about directories your user cannot read

   ```
   find  \( -iname "*rstudio*" -or -iname "*R Studio*" \) -printf '%h\n' 2> /dev/null | sort -u
   ```
2. Find files containing one of these strings.

   ```
   grep -ilR -E 'R Studio|rstudio' /
   ```

   Here, we run a recursive (`-R`) grep with extended regular expressions (`-E`) and tell it to find either of the two strings. The `-l` tells grep to just print the name of the file, not the matched line from it. As above, to avoid warnings, add `2> /dev/null` or run as root.

Comment: those will need `sudo`. It will be a lot quicker to use `locate` for finding the files. and you need `-i` for grep to ignore case. you answer snatcher :+ Gratz on 100k *O*

Comment: @Rinzwind yes, that's why I have a whole sentence explaining that you need to  either add `2> /dev/null` or run as root if you want to avoid permission denied warnings. I don't like telling people to use `sudo` when I don't know it is needed. for all I know, the OP is only interested in files they have access to. As for locate, yes, but I don't know how to combine the two options for it. Still, running `sudo updatedb` and then two `locate` commands will still be much faster than find, but then you have issues with weird file names to get the dir etc.

Comment: Go ahead and post the `locate` answer, @Rinzwind, looking forward to reading it! And thanks :)

Comment: @terdon - Thank you for the detailed answer! I'll be trying it out soon. A question regarding (1): Is that equivalent to `find / \( -iname "rstudio*" \) -exec dirname {} \; | sort -u 2> /dev/null` (since the string can be any combination of lower- and upper-cases). Also, suggesting an edit for your answer (which I am not allowed to do): please escape the closing parathesis after the second `-name "*R Studio*"`.

Comment: @koustav_ch not quite. I hadn't realized that you need this case insensitive since you only mentioned `R Studio`.  See updated answer. Yours would only find things _starting with_ `rstudio`, and wouldn't find `R Studio`. Also, you need to redirect the errors of find, not sort.

Comment: Also, do try `locate -i rstudio; locate -i "R studio"` as @Rinzwind suggested, that will do a much better job at finding the file names.

Comment: I was a bit late  had to play some persona 3 reload :D :D

Comment: @terdon You can greatly speed that up by 157x (0.942s vs 0.006s with `find /run/user/1000 [...]`) with s/`-exec dirname {} \;`/`-printf '%h\n'`/g (stolen from Raffa's comment on my post yesterday).

Comment: @terdon - Thank you for your reply! Yes, you're right; since I needed the command to _ignore cases_, and also needed it to consider `any_character` _before_ or _in between_ or _after_ the `r` and the `studio` strings. So for that, I should have written `*r*studio*` along with `iname` in my previous comment.

Comment: @terdon - Also, thank you for the updated answer! I'll try that now. One suggested edit (since I am getting this message `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`)'`): please escape the closing parenthesis `)` by a ``\`` character in all your commands.

Comment: Eek, thanks, that was a typo @koustav_ch! Also, please see updated answer that incorporates Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @DanielT, good point!

Comment: Thank you @terdon! I'll check 'em all out. :) So much to learn about searching!

Answer (score 5):

`locate` is perfect for looking for files and directories.

```
locate -i rstudio
locate -i "R studio"
```

Easy to remember and it will be the quickest method as it uses its own cache to show the results. It also always shows the full path. If you use `-c` you only get the number of files found. `-0` will use NULL as separator so make it a one-liner.

It probably is not installed: `sudo apt install plocate` and to update its database: `sudo updatedb`.

Searching inside files is in Terdon's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! :) On the mac terminal using `bash`, `locate` was installed but `updatedb` was not. But then I was able to use `locate.updatedb`.